# c# string Trim() method: how to get the spaces/escape characters which were trimmed out?

Tags: c#, xml, string

I'm trying to use the string.Trim() function in C# when reading an XML file, which is formatted with indents. I use it to trim each line (get rid of spaces/tabs before the tag) so that I can analyze just the tag in my loop conditions. I want to print the whole line including the spaces into a listbox. I have figured out a way to do it (just take the string of the line itself and print) but I was wondering if I would be able to print the trimmed out spaces, then print the string of just the tag. Is there a string function which retains what is trimmed out and allows me to use it again?

Edit: in response to if I am reading it as plain text (don't really know if I am..) this is the code which reads the XML file and writes it into listbox 1. I am writing certain parts of it into listbox 2

```
string line;
System.IO.StreamReader file = newSystem.IO.StreamReader(@"directorylocation");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{listBox1.Items.Add(line);}
file.Close();
```

Comment: You're parsing an XML file by reading it as plain text?

Comment: I edited the post with some code

Comment: You really should load the xml into an XDoc and work from there, it would be 1000% easier and MUCH less prone to errors.

Comment: Alright thanks for the suggestion

Comment: If someone could answer my question about string functions that would be great too.

Comment: XML files ignore spaces when you read them properly.

Comment: If you need to know how to remove leading/trailing whitespace, use `Trim()` - `listBox1.Items.Add(line.Trim());`